# Include OCaml binary library

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use the OcamlGraph library and it's not clear to me how to add it to my project. It was suggested to me that I just compile the source of the library along with the source of my project, but there has to be some way of linking the binary of a precompiled library without using OPAM. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**compiling:**

```
ocamlc -I /path/to/ocamlgraph -c mysource.ml
```

(as suggested by `ocamlfind ocamlc -package ocamlgraph -c -only-show`, if ocamlfind and ocamlgraph are installed)

**linking:**

```
ocamlc -I /path/to/ocamlgraph /path/to/ocamlgraph/graph.cma mysource.cmo -o test.byte
```

(as suggested by `ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package ocamlgraph -only-show` )

But normally, you should use ocamlfind and the ocamlgraph package of opam or your distribution.